# How to move line vertically while skipping over collapsed sections in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can move lines of code using (on the Mac) <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd> or <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd>. If I've collapsed (folded) a block of code, though, when I move the lines of code it enters the collapsed code blocks rather than skips over them. Is there a way to configure the editor so that moving text skips over the folded code blocks?

Comment: Also would like to know, did you manage? @Natty :)

Comment: I never found a way to do this.